# AngularJS get value from HTML

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am using AngularJS and Laravel to make one application at the moment.

I got an problem with my angularJS part so I would like to ask you help me to fix it.

I made different page for other value and do as same way, and it is working.
but, this code doesn't get any value from input/select.So I am confused...
Please help me if you find the bug from this code.Thank you.

HTML

```
    <div class="fa_content col-lg-10 col-md-10">
        <p class='successMsg'>{{successMsg}}</p>
        <p class='errorMsg'>{{errorMsg}}</p>
        <form name="InsuranceForm" ng-submit="createFA()">
          <tabset justified="true">
                <tab heading="Main">Main
                        <label>Asset code:</label><br/>
                        <input class="faText" name="dAssetCode"  ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="nameValid" ng-model="detailAssetCode"/><br/>

                        <label>Description:</label><br/>
                        <input class="faText" name="dDescription"  ng-pattern="alNumSymValid" ng-model="detailDescription"/>
                        <br/>
                        <label>Parchase Date:</label><br/>
                        <input type="date"  class="faDate"  name="dParchaseDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"  ng-model="detailParchaseDate" />

                        <br/>
                        <label>Sold Date:</label><br/>
                        <input type="date" class="faDate" name="dSoldDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"  ng-model="detailSoldDate" />
                        <br/>
                        <label>Asset Type:</label><br/>
                        <select class="faSelect" name="dAssetType" ng-model="detailAssetType" >
                            <option value="0">TypeA</option>
                            <option value="1">TypeBy</option>
                            <option value="2">TypeC</option>
                            <option value="3">TypeD</option>
                            <option value="4">TypeE</option>
                        </select><br/>


                    <label>Asset group:</label><br/>
                    <select class="faSelect" name="dAssetG" ng-model="detailAssetG">
                        <option value="1">Group0</option>
                        <option value="2">Group1</option>
                        <option value="3">Group2</option>
                        <option value="4">Group3t</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <label>Assigned to:</label><br/>
                    <select class="faSelect" name="dAssigned" ng-model="detailAssigned">

                        <option value="8">PARTNER</option>
                        <option value="9">INF.ADMIN</option>
                        <option value="10">STAFF</option>
                    </select><br>

                    <label>Serial Number:</label><br/>
                    <input class="faText" type="text" name="dSerial" ng-model="detailSerial"/><br/>
                    <label>Asset Barcode:</label><br/>
                    <input  class="faText" type="text" name="dBarcode" ng-model="detailBarcode"/><br/>

                    IsActive<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dIsActive" ng-model="detailIsActive"/><br/>

                </tab>

                <tab heading="Transaction"><h2>Transaction</h2>
                    <label>Transaction Date:</label><br/>
                        <input class="faDate" type="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="tDate" ng-model="transDate"  /><br/>

                    <label>Detail:</label><br/>
                        <input class="faText" name="tDetail" ng-model="transDetail"/><br/>
                    <label>Debit:</label><br/>
                        <input type="number" class="faText"  name="tDebit" step="0.1" min="0.1"  ng-model="transDebit"/><br/>


                    <label>Credit:</label><br/>
                    $<input class="faText" type="number" name="tCredit" placeholder="10.00"  ng-model="transCredit"/><br/>


                <tab heading="Warranty"><h2>Warrenty</h2>


                </tab>
                <tab heading="Insurance">

                    <h2>Insurance</h2>

                    </select><br>


                        <!--<span ng-show="InsuranceForm.logName.$error.required">Required</span>-->
                    <label>Policy Number:</label><br/>
                        <input class="faText" name="iPolNum" ng-model="ipolNum"/><br/>
                    <label>Insurance Expire Due:</label><br/>
                        <input type="date" class="faDate" name="iExpDue" ng-model="iExpDue" /><br/>

                    <label>Insurance Type:</label><br/>
                        <select class="faSelect"  name="iType" ng-model="iType">
                            <option value="9">Full Replacement</option>
                            <option value="10">Indemnity</option>
                            <option value="11">Sum Insured</option>

                        </select><br>
                    <label>Payment Freqency:</label><br/>
                        <select  class="faSelect" name="iPFreq" ng-model="iPFreq">
                            <option value="4">Weekly</option>
                            <option value="5">Fortnightly</option>
                            <option value="6">Every 4 weeks</option>
                            <option value="7">Monthly</option>
                            <option value="8">Every 8 weeks</option>
                            <option value="9">Every 12 weeks</option>
                            <option value="10">Quarterly</option>
                            <option value="11">Semi Annually</option>
                            <option value="12">Annually</option>

                        </select><br>
                    <label>Payment Type:</label><br/>
                        <select  class="faSelect" name="iPaymentType" ng-model="iPaymentType">
                            <option value="5">Automatic Payment</option>
                            <option value="6">Credit Card</option>
                            <option value="7">Direct Credit</option>
                            <option value="8">Direct Debit</option>
                        </select><br>
                    <label>Insurance Premium:</label><br/>
                        $<input class="faText" name="iPremNum" placeholder="10.00"  ng-model="iPremNum"/><br/>

                    <label>Details:</label><br/>
                        <textarea  class="textarea" name="iDetail" ng-model="iDetails">
                        </textarea><br/>
                    <label>conditions:</label><br/>
                        <textarea class="textarea" name="iConditions" ng-model="iConditions">
                        </textarea><br/>

                </tab>


                    <tab select="alertMe()" heading="Save">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn col-lg-10" name="save" value="Save" />
                    </tab>


          </tabset>

      </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

AngularJS controller

```
 'use strict';
app.controller('newFixedAssetCtrl', ['$scope','$window','Assets',function($scope,$window,Assets){
     $scope.tabs = [
                { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
                { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
     ];


//window.alert($scope.createData);
    $scope.createFA = function(create){ //$scope.acreateFAMainData is the function of (myController.php) function??
                            var faData ={
                                    detailAssetCode: $scope.detailAssetCode,
                                    detailDescription: $scope.detailDescription,
                                    detailParchaseDate: $scope.detailParchaseDate,
                                    detailSoldDate: $scope.detailSoldDate,
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                    ipolNum: $scope.ipolNum,
                                    iExpDue:$scope.iExpDue,
                                    iType: $scope.iType,
                                    iPFreq: $scope.iPFreq,
                                    iPaymentType : $scope.iPremNum,
                                    iPremNum: $scope.iPremNum,
                                    iDetails: $scope.iDetails,
                                    iConditions: $scope.iConditions,





                        }
                        console.log(faData);
                         Assets.save(faData);

                    }




     $scope.alertMe = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $window.alert('did you put all the data for this fixed asset? Click save button.');
        });
 };


 }]);
```

Service

```
app.factory('Assets', function($resource) {
return $resource('/api/assets/:assetId',{id:'@id'}); // Note the full endpoint address

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into the `.` problem as explained in this [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use
>
> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1" />
> ```
>
> rather than
>
> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="prop1" />
> ```

In your controller define a container object:

```
$scope.faData = {};
```

In your HTML:

```
ng-model="faData.detailAssetCode"

ng-model="faData.detailDescription"
```

etc.

In your `createFA` method:

```
$scope.createFA = function () {
    console.log($scope.faData);
    Assets.save($scope.faData);
};
```

Comment: Thanks it need to be defined with empty bracket, right ?

Comment: Yes it needs to be an object, so it should be {}, but it doesn't need to be an empty object, there can already be data in there as well as these variables you're binding to in the html.